# Informatica: How to load two sources of different schema into same target (flat file)?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Here is the scenario:

I have a source which contains invoice line details:

```
INV#    DATE    QTY     PRICE
123     12/16   1       50
123     12/16   2       20
```

I have another pipeline where I have aggregated the details to form the header

```
INV#    DATE    TOTALPRICE  PURCHASE#   LOC     TAX
123     12/16   70          456         1000    7
```

I want to sort and load both these records into the same tab-separated flat file using Informatica

Thus the flat-file output would be:

```
123     12/16   70      456     1000    7   
123     12/16   1       50
123     12/16   2       20
```

Any suggestions?

The only way I can think of is concatenating all the header and detail columns in one string and adding a union transformation to create one file.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is here.  Read the records and union them together with nulls for the columns you don't have (LOC, TAX).   How is this not just a simple union?

Comment: I agree with Hogan. Even whatever you said is right. You can concat them into a bigg string( mind that length can be upto 4000 only). Or, as hogan said, use union transformation and put null for non-available columns from first pipeline

Comment: Thanks Hogan and Koushik. I was just wondering if there is a better way to do this instead of using Union and Concat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps to have this done:

1) You need to create a new port(header_detail_ind) of type integer for the header and detail pipeline. For this you can use two expression transformations one for each pipeline. The header records should have a value of 1 for this port and the detail records should have a value of 2.

2) Next use a union transformation with both the pipelines as input. 
Use the expression transformations in the above step to make the output of both the pipeline(no of ports and datatype) same so that it can be mapped to the union transformation. You can add some empty fields in both the pipelines to achieve this.

3) Next add a sorter transformation and **sort** the data by **#INV** and the new port **header_detail_ind**. By this way you will have the header and the detail records in the order you expect.

4) Now you can use a expression transformation to prepare the output as required by the target definition. This will have one output port for each of the port required by the target definition. You can have different logics for the header and detail records which can be differentiated by the port header_detail_ind.

Answer (score -1):

You can write the records separately to the same file. First have the header pipeline create the file and write the header record. Then have the detail pipeline append records to it.

Comment: I think those "header" records occur for each INV#.  They don't just appear at the start of the file.